# Avogadro - all atoms are in (0,0,0) point

Tags: linux, linux-mint, avogadro

I am trying to build TS-1 model with MFI framework from IZA Database. However when I try to open .cif file downloaded form mentioned database all atoms appear in the origin point of a coordinate system. That problem does not occur on MacOS, only on my Linux Mint machine.

I tried to paste coordinates from .cif to Coordinate Editor but of course it did not work, due to coordinates being written as fractional ones.

Edit:
I use Avogadro 1.95.1 with Open Babel.

Comment: Avogadro runs on Linux. Sounds like you are converting coordinates to integer in Open Babel and doing rounding. Since you provide no details it's impossible to tell.

Comment: For future reference (and Google), I recommend asking questions on the [Avogadro forum](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/) or on the Matter Modeling SE